# Sending JSON object as a POST request

Tags: json, vba, excel

I'm trying to send a JSON object from a VBA application in Excel.  The code below sends the request correctly, however I can't figure out how to make the request with the JSON object in the body.

```vb
Sub Post()

    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    URL = "http://localhost:3000/test"
    objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send "test=6"

End Sub
```

If I try for instance to send `"{test:6, test2: 7}"` and log the body of the request on the server I get `{ '{parts:6, test: 7}': '' }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you probably already know, JSON structure can really produce serious headaches. In your case, I would say its all about the quotes, as you can see in [here](http://jsonlint.com/) if you try to validate your `{test:6, test2: 7}`.

Try the following code. It looks plausible to me:

```vb
    Sub Post()
    
    Dim URL As String, JSONString As String, objHTTP as Object
    
        Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        URL = "http://localhost:3000/test"
        objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
        objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
        objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    
        JSONString = "{""test"": 6,""test2"":7}"
    
        objHTTP.Send JSONString
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! this did eventually solve the problem.  Before this though I had to change the content-type header to application/json and add a content length filed to get rid of a 400 error.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is struggling with this for POSTS, where your body isn't being sent at all, specifically when using a variable instead of literal text at the objHTTP.Send line, this worked for me, after struggling with it for hours, despite declaring my variables as strings:

```
    objHTTP.Send CStr(YourVariable)
```

This did NOT work for me, as I've seen posted elsewhere:

```
    objHTTP.Send CStr(YourVariable, vbFromUnicode)
```